# How can i make a matrix filled with a sequence for the rows and columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I want to create a matrix with an complex part and a real part.
The values from the colums should go from [-2.0 -> 1.0] with 300 steps
The values from the rows should go from [-1.5 -> 1.5] with steps of 300, this is also the complex part.

I can make a matrix of 301 X 301 and fill this with zeros. But then i need the fill in the values. I don't know how i to do that. I was thinking using a double for loop but don't know ,how to implement this.

this is what i would like to get

```
[ array([[-2.00+1.5j, -1.99+1.5j, ..., 1.00+1.5j ], [ ..., ..., ..., ... ] [-2.00-1.5j ,-1.99-1.5j, ..., 1.00-1.5j ]]) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an [open grid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) and sum it:

```
sum(np.ogrid[1.5j:-1.5j:301j,-2:1:301j])
```

Comment: this looks nice, can you also show it with a double forloop?

Comment: @Marco I probably could, but good numpy style is all about avoiding for loops (because they are very slow by comparison).